# raw_input function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

What is the `raw_input` function? Is it a user interface? When do we use it?

Comment: Use `input()` instead. The function `raw_input` is no longer included in python.

Comment: Related post - [How do I use raw_input in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954834/465053)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

It presents a prompt to the user (the optional `arg` of `raw_input([arg])`), gets input from the user and returns the data input by the user in a string. See the docs for [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Example:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "Hello, %s." % name
```

This differs from [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)  in that the latter tries to interpret the input given by the user; it is usually best to avoid `input()` and to stick with `raw_input()` and custom parsing/conversion code.

*Note: This is for Python 2.x*

Comment: For Python 3:

name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hello, %s." % name)

Answer (score 117):

`raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python 3.

From http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: Can we use one for both versions?

Answer (score 6):

`raw_input` is a form of input that takes the argument  in the form of a string whereas the input function takes the value depending upon your input.
Say, `a=input(5)` returns a as an integer with value 5 whereas
 `a=raw_input(5)` returns a as a string of "5"

Answer (score 4):

The "input" function converts the input you enter as if it were python code. "raw_input" doesn't convert the input and takes the input as it is given. Its advisable to use raw_input for everything.
Usage:

```
>>a = raw_input()
>>5
>>a
>>'5'
```

Answer (score 2):

The raw_input() function reads a line from input (i.e. the user) and returns a string

Python v3.x as raw_input() was renamed to input()

PEP 3111: raw_input() was renamed to input(). That is, the new input() function reads a line from sys.stdin and returns it with the trailing newline stripped. It raises EOFError if the input is terminated prematurely. To get the old behavior of input(), use eval(input()).

[Ref: Docs Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another example method, to mix the prompt using print, if you need to make your code simpler.

Format:-

x = raw_input () -- This will return the user input as a string

x= int(raw_input()) -- Gets the input number as a string from raw_input() and then converts it to an integer using int().

```
print '\nWhat\'s your name ?', 
name = raw_input('--> ')
print '\nHow old are you, %s?' % name,
age = int(raw_input())
print '\nHow tall are you (in cms), %s?' % name,
height = int(raw_input())
print '\nHow much do you weigh (in kgs), %s?' % name,
weight = int(raw_input())

print '\nSo, %s is %d years old, %d cms tall and weighs %d kgs.\n' %(
name, age, height, weight)
```

Answer (score -1):

> If I let raw_input like that, no Josh or anything else.
>   It's a variable,I think,but I don't understand her roll :-(

The raw_input function prompts you for input and
returns that as a string. This certainly worked for
me. You don't need idle. Just open a "DOS prompt"
and run the program.

This is what it looked like for me:

```
C:\temp>type test.py
print "Halt!"
s = raw_input("Who Goes there? ")
print "You may pass,", s

C:\temp>python test.py
Halt!
Who Goes there? Magnus
You may pass, Magnus
```

I types my name and pressed `[Enter`] after the program
had printed "Who Goes there?"