# Where is raw_input implemented in the cpython source code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been looking through the 2.7 branch of cpython and can't seem to find any reference to it.

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/014060738f7f/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2299 or Python 3.4's `input()`: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dd1dffe6f0d2/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1662

Comment: possible duplicate of [raw\_input function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563089/raw-input-function-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c (search for builtin_raw_input)