# How to read the data from a file and get the concordance output

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, for-loop

I have the code which will throw the output from the given string.

```
inputdata = "HELLO HELLO HELLO BOBBY WHAT ARE YOU DOING"
myDict = {}
linenum = 0

for word in inputdata.split():
    if not word in myDict:
        myDict[word] = []

    myDict[word].append(linenum)


print "%-15s %-15s" %("Word", "Frequency")
for key in sorted(myDict):
    print '%-15s: %-15d' % (key, len(myDict[key]))
```

the output would be

```
   Word            Frequency     
 ARE           : 1              
 BOBBY         : 1              
 DOING         : 1              
 HELLO         : 3              
 WHAT          : 1              
 YOU           : 1
```

But when I tried to replace the string with .txt file, Script was prompting the popup to enter the text instead of reading the data from the .txt file.

```
f = open(raw_input("eng.txt"), "r")
myDict = {}
linenum = 0

for word in f.split():
    if not word in myDict:
        myDict[word] = []

    myDict[word].append(linenum)


print "%-15s %-15s" %("Word", "Frequency")
for key in sorted(myDict):
    print '%-15s: %-15d' % (key, len(myDict[key]))
```

Comment: dont use raw_input, just do open("eng.txt","r")

Comment: I have tried the same, but it doesn't show any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes:**

[raw_input method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563089/raw-input-function-in-python) is used to get user input from prompt

**Changes to your own code:**

```
f = open("eng.txt", "r")
myDict = {}
linenum = 0

for word in f.read().split():
    if not word in myDict:
        myDict[word] = []
    myDict[word].append(linenum)

print "%-15s %-15s" %("Word", "Frequency")
for key in sorted(myDict):
    print '%-15s: %-15d' % (key, len(myDict[key]))
```

Simplified code using set [default method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm) of dictionary

**Code1:**

```
myDict = {}
linenum = 0
with open("eng.txt", "r") as f:
    for word in f.read().split():
        myDict.setdefault(word,[]).append(linenum)

print "%-15s %-15s" %("Word", "Frequency")
for key in sorted(myDict):
    print '%-15s: %-15d' % (key, len(myDict[key]))
```

**Sample input:**

```
was very very afraid can you help
me
me
me
```

**Output :**

```
Word            Frequency      
afraid         : 1              
can            : 1              
help           : 1              
me             : 3              
very           : 2              
was            : 1              
you            : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`f` is a file resource in your example, not a string. You need to read from `f`. See here for example: [How do I read a text file into a string variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python)

Do something like the following to also deal with `newline` characters:

```
with open ("data.txt", "r") as myfile:
    f=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Also `raw_input` is for command prompt and is not useful in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) there:

```
std::istringstream inputdata("HELLO HELLO HELLO BOBBY WHAT ARE YOU DOING");

std::string word;
std::map<std::string, size_t> counts;

while (inputdata >> word)
    ++counts[word];

for (auto const &w : counts)
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << w.first << ": " << w.second << "\n";
```

Note that I've skipped producing/storing the line numbers since you didn't use them anyway. :-)