# Get Better Time Complexity

Tags: python, arrays, list, while-loop, time-complexity

This code is for **asserting values** **into** the **list** **until** the user inputs a **negative number.**

**Is there a way better to implement it?**

Below is my tried version.

```
i = -1
while i > -1:
    x = raw_input("Enter array limit")
    for i in limit(x):
        listArr = list()
        y = raw_input("Enter number")
        y.append(listArr)
        print (listArr)
```

Comment: Quite a lot of criteria! Also, what have you tried, and what isn't working?

Comment: Please show that you've tried this yourself. Otherwise it seems like you just want people to write code for you

Comment: I am new in the coding area, just curious to know  the answer

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should meet the requirements:

```
odds = []                     # similiar to `listArr` but we only want odd numbers

limit = 5

for _ in range(limit):        # Input 5 numbers into an array
    y = int(input('Enter number: '))        
    if y > -1 and y % 2 !=0:  # if odd number
        odds.append(y)        # add to array
    else:
        break                 # break after a negative number as input 

if odds:
    print(min(odds))          # and display minimum odd number 
                              # and if no negative integer input then also display minimum odd number 
else:
    print(0)                  # and if no odd number display zero
```

If Python2 use [`raw_input()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563089/raw-input-function-in-python) as used in question code, otherwise use [`input()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30991566/1248974).