# Multiple inputs in a line python

Tags: python

How to get multiple inputs in one line in Python?

Here's what I want:

**Python Input**:

```
Enter name and age respectively: Subha 18
```

**Output**:

```
Your Name Is Subha and Your age is 18 years
```

Here is what I tried:

```py
inp = input()

x = inp.split()

print x[0]   # Won't work
print x[1]
```

The error is (console):

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "source_file.py", line 3, in <module>
inp = input()
File "<string>", line 1
11 22
   ^
```

Comment: Related question: [raw_input function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563089/raw-input-function-in-python)

Comment: time to switch to Python 3 before support for 2 ends?

Comment: @Aprillion i will think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `raw_input`:

```
inp = raw_input()

x = inp.split()

print x[0]
print x[1]
```

Comment: but i think raw_input is for python 2?

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3**

There are multiple ways to get input in one line python statement, but that totally depends on data type choice.

For storing data in variable

```
x,y = map(data_type,input().split())
```

e.g.;

```
x,y = map(int,input().split())
```

For storing data in the list.

```
list_name = list(map(data_type,intput().split())
```

or

```
list_name = [data_type(input()) for i in range(n)]
```

for n could be range of input.

For storing input in the dictionary.

```
dict1= dict(zip(range(n),list(map(int,input().split()))) )
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3

`>>> init_input = input("Enter name and age respectively, e.g 'Shubha 18': ")`

Enter name and age respectively, e.g 'Shubha 18': **Marcus 21**

`>>> values = init_input.split(" ")`
Returns a list:
`['Marcus', '21']`

The split() method returns a list of all the words in the string, taking the separator as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Taking two inputs at a time:

```
a, b = input("Enter a two value: ").split()
```