# My code still won't work if I input multiple attachments in python

Tags: python

My code is now working but only if I input 1 value but if I input 2 values, it won't work. Example (I will input monolithic_suppressor;owc_skeleton_stock) the compiler wont read it. I want to input multiple attachments that add or subtract the following attributes on the man o war stats.

```py
damage = 49
fire_rate = 50
accuracy = 69
mobility = 59
shooting_range = 56
controls = 53

attachments = "monolithic_suppressor;owc_skeleton_stock;owc_laser_tactical;operator_foregrip".split(";")
attachment = str(input("What attachment would you like to add? ")).lower()

while True:
    if attachment not in attachments:
        break
    elif attachment == attachments[0]:
         damage += 5  
         mobility -= 5
    elif attachment == attachments[1]:
         mobility += 5 
         accuracy -= 8
    elif attachment == attachments[2]:
         accuracy += 5 
         controls += 5
    elif attachment == attachments[3]:
         controls += 10 
         mobility += 2
    print(f"""\n Man O War Updated Stats!\n Damage: {damage}\n Fire Rate: {fire_rate}\n Accuracy: {accuracy} \n Mobility: {mobility}\n Range: {shooting_range} \n Control: {controls}
    """)
    break
```

Comment: Ideally, you should be posting a new question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple inputs in a line python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238707/multiple-inputs-in-a-line-python)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `split()` method to `attachments` variable instead.

```
attachments = "monolithic_suppressor;owc_skeleton_stock;owc_laser_tactical;operator_foregrip".split(";")
attachment = str(input("What attachment would you like to add? ")).lower()
```

Also, your if condition needs to be like this

```
if attachment == attachments[0]:
    damage += 5
    mobility-= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Always ask for input outside the loop.
Keep asking with `continue` in case of errors.
Check with `if var == something` of `if var in something`.

```
damage = 49
fire_rate = 50
accuracy = 69
mobility = 59
shooting_range = 56
controls = 53

attachments = "monolithic_suppressor;owc_skeleton_stock;owc_laser_tactical;operator_foregrip".split(";")
print(f"Options are {attachments}")
attachment = (input("What attachment would you like to add? ")).lower()


while True:
        if attachment not in attachments:
            attachment = (input("Incorrect Option.What attachment would you like to add? ")).lower()
            continue
        elif attachment in attachments[0]:
             damage += 5  
             mobility -= 5
        elif attachment in attachments[1]:
             mobility += 5 
             accuracy -= 8
        elif attachment in attachments[2]:
             accuracy += 5 
             controls += 5
        elif attachment in attachments[3]:
             controls += 10 
             mobility += 2
        print(f"""\n Damage: {damage}\n Fire Rate: {fire_rate}\n Accuracy: {accuracy} \n Mobility: {mobility}\n Range: {shooting_range} \n Control: {controls}
        """)
        break
```