# Regarding raw_input.split() function in python

Tags: python, split, raw-input

How does   this line exactly works in python `raw_input().split()` ?

Comment: have you tried googling it?

Comment: it reads the one string line as input and split it based on space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `input()` prompts the user for input. The user enters a series of characters that is a string. Then, the `split()` function separates the string from the user into a list of words (or groups of characters) and returns list of these words or grouped characters. By default, each element in the list is separated by a blankspace. See the below examples.

```
words = input().split() # Typed "These are the input words"
print(words)
```

**Output:**

```
['These', 'are', 'the', 'input', 'words']
```

You can also specify a specific character other than a blank space to split on in the `split()` method. For example, in this instance, the input string is split upon occurrences of a `'1'`.

```
words = input().split('1') # Typed "100120023104"
print(words)
```

**Output:**

```
['', '00', '20023', '04']
```

Note that the `split()` will omit the character requested to split the input string on (blankspace ' ' by default) in the returned list.

Also, `raw_input()` is [no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563089/raw-input-function-in-python) in Python3. `raw_input()` was supported by older versions of Python2. Now, we just use `input()` in Python3 and it works the same way. You should upgrade your environment to Python3 if you are still using `raw_input()`.