# (python 3) When using raw_input(), why does the function add "\n" to the input?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, raw-input

I searched the first page of Google but couldn't find an answer. This won't happen for int(raw_input()) weirdly enough. But if i type:

```
a = [raw_input() for i in range(int(raw_input()))]
print(a)
```

Example input:
5
1
2
3
4
5

The output will be:
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n']

I know this has something to do with the IDE (I run VSCode) but I have no clue how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: just use `int(input())` instead of `int(raw_input())`. Raw input will return you all the details including the \n

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-input-and-raw_input-functions-in-python/. Also see more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563089/raw-input-function-in-python

Comment: @JoeFerndz Thanks, but that's not my question, int(raw_input()) works fine. But raw_input() at some random point today began adding \n to each input when it never did that before.  I need to use raw_input because it shaves off a decent amount of time off my CP submissions. I'm not interested in the niche uses of raw_input, I'm looking at how to fix this bug.

Comment: raw_input() will always return a string value. You need to convert it to an integer if you want integer.

Comment: btw, if you are using 3.9 or above, PEP 3111: raw_input() was renamed to input(). That is, the new input() function reads a line from sys.stdin and returns it with the trailing newline stripped. It raises EOFError if the input is terminated prematurely. To get the old behavior of input(), use eval(input()).

Comment: @JoeFerndz thanks for replying but that's not my question. Raw_input never did this before, and it's clearly a mistake of my IDE of some sort. I'm asking how to reverse this.

Comment: @JoeFerndz I think that could be the answer thanks

Comment: As far as i know, raw_input (on any IDE) should return you a string. You have to explicitly convert it into an int() if you want it to be an int

Comment: btw. what version of python are you using?

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes I'm aware raw_input will convert integer inputs into strings automatically. But it has never added \n at the end for no reason it seems. I experimented and type input = sys.stdin.readline and it's actually giving me the same problem

Comment: See if this helps. Not sure if this is something you can try. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10529

Comment: i will vote to keep the question open so others in the community can provide guidance to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python3.x, `raw_input()` and `input()` are integrated, `raw_input()` is removed, only the `input()` function is retained, which receives any input, defaults all input to string processing, and returns the string type.

When use Python2.7:

[image]

When use Python3.8:

[image]

In addition, if you use extensions for debugging other than the python extension in VS Code, please try to disable it to avoid affecting the results.

My environment:

VS Code: 1.52.1 (user setup);
OS: Windows_NT x64;
VS Code extension: Python; Pylance;

Reference: [What's new in Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins).

Comment: You're goated. It was because of a new python update. Thanks